# Адаптивная верстка. Как НЕ масштабировать маленькие изображения?

Tags: css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Часть изображений на сайте нельзя масштабировать без потери качества картинки, их ширина `200px`. Все изображения большие и маленькие заключаются в `div`

```
<div><img src="" width="" height="" /></div>
```

как сделать исключение для маленьких изображений, если для большинства походит вариант с `img {width:100%}`?

Comment: max-width: 100% ?

Answer (score 2):

Для тех изображений которые не нужно масштабировать поставить фиксированную ширину, например `img {width: 200px}`, а для тех которые нужно масштабировать относительную `img {width:100%}`.

Comment: то есть присвоить классы.

Comment: Можно присвоить классы, а можно непосредственно в рисунок прописать ширину. Например <img href="адрес картинки" width="200px" alt="картинка" /> или <img href="адрес картинки" style="width: 200px;" alt="картинка" />

Comment: спасибо, думала, есть возможность обойтись только css без редактирования html